# How to get the customer email by customer id in magento2 admin grid

Tags: magento2, customer, grid, magento2.4.1

How to get the customer email by customer id in magento2 admin grid. in my table I have customer id based on customer id get the email id in the admin custom grid.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\RewardPointsReportdata\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\RewardPointsReportdata\Collection as RewardPointsReportCollection;

/**
 * Collection for displaying grid of banners slider
 */
class Collection extends RewardPointsReportCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AggregationInterface
     */
    protected $aggregations;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $eventPrefix
     * @param string $eventObject
     * @param string $resourceModel
     * @param string $model
     * @param string|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all ids for collection
     * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: provide grid collection  code

Comment: added the collection code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create File:

Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerEmail.php

```
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
/**
 * Class CustomerEmail
*/
 class CustomerEmail extends Column
 {
    private $urlBuilder;

    protected $helper;

    const CUSTOMER_URL_PATH_EDIT = 'customer/index/edit';
    
    public function __construct(
       ContextInterface $context,
       UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
       \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
       UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
       array $components = [],
       array $data = []
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, 
       $components, $data
    );
       $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
       $this->helper = $helper;
  public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
   {
       if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
         foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
             $name = $this->getData('name');
             if (isset($item['customer_id'])) {
                $CustomerEmail = $this->helper->getCustomerEmail($item['customer_id']);
                //@codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $item[$name] = html_entity_decode(
                    '<a href="' .
                    $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        self::CUSTOMER_URL_PATH_EDIT,
                        [
                            'id' => $item['customer_id'],
                        ]
                    )
                    . '" target="_blank" >' . $CustomerEmail . '</a>'
                );
                //@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
  }
```

Add below code in your Grid XML

```
 <actionColumn name="customer_id" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerEmail">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Email</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Create Helper File:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
  protected $_customers;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
) {
    $this->_customers = $customers;
}

public function getCustomerEmail($id)
{
    $customer = $this->_customers->load($id);
    return $customer->getEmail();
}
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: where we use this getData() function ?

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: email search filter not working

Comment: $customer = $this->_customers->load($id);

try this on the grid with 500+ items and you'll see where the bottleneck is.